# What is "G-d intended"?

Tags: python, urlparse

I see `G-d intended` below. I don't understand what it means does anybody know? Thanks.

```
Help on function parse_qsl in module urlparse:

parse_qsl(qs, keep_blank_values=0, strict_parsing=0)
    Parse a query given as a string argument.

    Arguments:

    qs: percent-encoded query string to be parsed

    keep_blank_values: flag indicating whether blank values in
        percent-encoded queries should be treated as blank strings.  A
        true value indicates that blanks should be retained as blank
        strings.  The default false value indicates that blank values
        are to be ignored and treated as if they were  not included.

    strict_parsing: flag indicating what to do with parsing errors. If
        false (the default), errors are silently ignored. If true,
        errors raise a ValueError exception.

    Returns a list, as G-d intended.
```

Comment: I imagine it's a reference to [Guido van Rossum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum)

Comment: @metatoaster I don't understand what is the purpose of `as God intended`. So it can be simplified as just `Returns a list`.

Comment: Yes, I don't know why that is even in the docstring at all when [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qsl) explain this better - they should have the sentence "Returns a list of name, value pairs" instead of this confusing statement.

Answer (score 1):

This code was [committed in 1999](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/1946f0d6f22987b1616b0935f577e805ca494db8)<sup>*</sup>.  From the commit message:

> ... [A] new function parse_qsl(), which is like
>
> parse_qs() but returns a list of (name, value) pairs -- which is
> actually more correct.  Use this where it makes sense.

Evidently the programmer believed that returning a list of name value pairs was *more correct* than returning a dictionary.  Thus the phrase "As G-d intended" is a humorous way of asserting that returning a list is better than returning a dictionary.  Bear in mind that the Python community in 1999 was much smaller and quirkier than today: humour in commit messages (and common use of Monty Python references in the community and ecosystem) was not unusual.

The original programmer might have been referring to how query strings with repeated keys are handled.  It could be argued that `parse_qsl` returns the original data, in order, whereas `parse_qs` does not.

```
>>> pairs = [('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
>>> qs = parse.urlencode(pairs)
>>> qs
'a=1&a=2&b=3'
>>> parse.parse_qs(qs)
{'a': ['1', '2'], 'b': ['3']}
>>> parse.parse_qsl(qs)
[('a', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('b', '3')]
```

<sup>*</sup> In the original commit the divine reference is unobfuscated.  The obfuscation was introduced as part of [this commit](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/afde7e24b6c7cd75e1797a02fa6c3674f6419531), without specific explanation.